# Replacing numpy 2D array elements below an index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I searched prior questions and didn't find one that quite fits this.

I am setting the value of all cells in A's *j*th column to 0 whose *row indeces* are less than m[j]:

```
import numpy as np
n = 8
A = np.ones([n,n])
m = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4])
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(m[j]):
        A[i,j] = 0
```

How do I rewrite that script without 'for' loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [broadcasted NumPy comparison](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)—

```
>>> A[np.arange(n)[:, None] < m] = 0
>>> 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Here, calling `[:, None]` augments the shape of `np.arange(n)` such that the comparison `<` is broadcasted across every element of `m`, for each item in the range. This generates a boolean mask of the same shape as `A` which is then used to set values to 0.

Note—If `A` is guaranteed to be an array of ones, I would recommend [Divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50362710/4909087), which is very similar to this.

Answer (score 3):

Use outer-broadcasted comparison against the ranged array of length `n` to get directly get `A` -

```
A = (m <=  np.arange(n)[:,None]).astype(float)
```

To boost up the performance, we could use the type conversion to lower precision ones, like `.astype(np.int)` or even `.astype(np.uint8)`. If you are okay with a boolean array, skip the type conversion altogether.

For `int` dtypes, we can also simply `view` into it, that saves us some memory -

```
(m <=  np.arange(n)[:,None]).view(np.int8)
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sense to initialise A like this if the input is all ones to  begin with. +1